# Docker application upload on AWS elastic beanstalk fails

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker

I am using docker images for running web-app on **PHP** and **MongoDB**. Docker container is running perfectly on my local machine (Windows10) but it is not updating on **AWS Elastic Beanstalk**. I have made a zipped file consist of `run.sh`, `Dockerfile`, and `Dockerrun.aws.json` which can be found from [here](https://jaijeetsingh@bitbucket.org/jaijeetsingh/phpmongo.git).

On **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** I am using single docker container and instance type is **Linux Docker Version 1.11.2** . after deploying I am getting following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `run.sh` needs to be executable, based on this inspection of the files:

```
ls
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x    7 adam  238 Jan 11 11:04 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 139 adam 4.7K Jan 11 11:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x   12 adam  408 Jan 11 11:04 .git
-rw-r--r--    1 adam 1.9K Jan 11 11:04 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 adam  248 Jan 11 11:04 Dockerrun.aws.json
-rw-r--r--    1 adam  544 Jan 11 11:04 index.php
-rw-r--r--    1 adam   72 Jan 11 11:04 run.sh
```

It's possible that you have other issues, but running `chmod +x run.sh` before you recreate the zip file should fix that specific problem.

Comment: Thanks @amcelwee it was really helpful! Can you please explain why what I did earlier wasn't working?

Comment: The line `CMD ["/run.sh"]` in your `Dockerfile` needs `run.sh` to be something it can execute but your file lacked the executable permission.